# On a variant of Carlson’s theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

My question is on whether or not there exists some monotone strictly decreasing sequence of positive numbers $c_1>c_2>\ldots$ such that given any $f$ which is a uniformly bounded holomorphic function in the right half of the complex plane with
$$ |f(k)|\leq c_k \quad \forall\, k\in \mathbb N,$$
there holds $ f(z)=0$ on the right half plane.

Comment: The answer is certainly "yes" (by the standard compactness argument) but I suspect that much more is known to the experts, so I'll leave it to them to answer your question properly.

Comment: For example $c_k=\exp(-k^{1+\epsilon})$ will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Condition
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log|c_n|}{n}=-\infty$$
is sufficient for $f=0$.

Since $f(z)=e^{-cz}$ and $c_n=e^{-cn}$ satisfy all
conditions, we see that this is best possible in certain sense.

This follows for example from a (much more general) theorem of N. Levinson, Gap and density theorems, AMS, 1940, page 121.
Levinson's theorem allows some growth of $F$, and much more general class of
sequences instead of integers.

Remark. In fact Levinson generalizes a theorem of Vladimir Bernstein 1932
(Theorem 32 in Levinson's book), which also implies the result that I stated.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to deduce a (possibly weaker) version of this result by the fact that the integers are a uniqueness set for bounded holomorphic functions in the half-plane?

Comment: See @fedja's comment to the question. Quntitave estimates are quite different for the condition that $f(n)$ is small, vs the condition $f(n)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice the comment of @fedja. However, I do not see how to use compactness to prove the existence of a sequence as in the statement.